# C++ with #include<string> and getting C2679

Tags: c++

Thank you to @crashmstr for triggering the right brain cells to work.  My problem is that you can't have an integer written into an array with that format.
cin>>votes[a][0]; was the right answer to the problem.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<istream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
const int nameRow = 6, nameCol = 7, voteRow = 6, voteCol = 2;

int main ( )
{
    char candName[nameRow][nameCol];
    int votes[voteRow][voteCol];
    for(int a=0;a< nameRow;a++)
        for (int b = 0; b < nameCol;b++)        
            candName[a][b] = 0;
    for (int c = 0; c < voteRow;c++)
        for (int d = 0; d < voteCol;d++)
            votes[c][d] = 0;


    cout << "Enter a candidate's name : ";
    for (int a = 0;a < nameRow;a++)
    {
        cin >> candName[a], nameCol;
        cin >> votes[a], voteCol;
    }

    system ( "pause" );
}
```

My problem is the last cin of the file.  The >> is getting the code.  It doesn't matter if I put it in  the same line, another loop, same function different loops or different functions all together the >> of that line is tripping C2679.
The most popular fix I have seen is having `#include<string.h>`and changing that to `<string>`.  I didn't initially have it but I added it when I saw it but it hasn't fixed anything.
Can anyone give me some insight of what I am missing?

Error message:

```
binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int[2]' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Comment: `cin >> candName[a], nameCol;` <-- the `,` does not belong here, did you mean to have another `>>`?

Comment: @crashmstr, No, that is actually how it works.  If I // the votes line I can put a c-string in that displays and prints like it should.

Comment: It would be good to copy and paste the complete error message into the question

Comment: [C2679](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2679?view=vs-2019): binary 'operator' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'type' (or there is no acceptable conversion).  The real error message will specify the operator and type.

Comment: Its the >> operator attached to int[2]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4Vda.png

Comment: @JeffA Please post the error message verbatim as plain-text into the question. You can [edit] it in. Also explain what you intend the lines to do. `,` makes no sense there and you cannot write to `const` variables, such as `nameCol`. You also cannot read in an `int` array, so what is `cin >> votes[a]` supposed to do?

Comment: You don't need `#include<string>` at all in your current program. You should however use `std::string` instead of `char` arrays and for `std::string` it *is* needed. The error message is not related to that.

Comment: Again, the `,` does not do what you think it does. Also, you are missing a subscript for the `votes`, as you cannot `cin` an array of ints like that -> `cin >> votes[a][???];`

Comment: @crashmstr, you sir/ma'am are a genious.  The fix is cin>>votes[a][0];  I could have sworn I tried that today.  Please put your comment as an answer and I will mark it as the fix.

Comment: @JeffA The problem is more likely that you want `int votes[voteRow];` instead of `int votes[voteRow][voteCol];` as M.M's answer demonstrates. What is the second dimension of the `int` array supposed to represent?

Comment: at the bottom of the first column is going to be the total.  The second column is going to be the percentage of votes each candidate received

Comment: @JeffA ok, then `cin >> votes[a][0];` or the like is the solution, but without you explaining that in the question, we cannot know that. For the next time please explain exactly what you intend the problematic lines of code to do. Often thinking about how to explain that already helps finding the solution to the problem yourself as well.

Comment: @walnut i understand, I have been trying to figure this out for a couple hours before posting and came up empty.  I was stuck on the failure code and trying to figure out what that meant.  I am embarrassed this was such an easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

Using `#include <string>` is part of a solution but you forgot to actually use the string type. Also you use a lot of antique stuff. The code could look like:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>

const int numRows = 6;

int main ( )
{
    std::string candName[numRows];      // empty strings
    int votes[numRows] {};              // zero-initialized

    for (int a = 0;a < numRows;a++)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a candidate's name : ";
        std::cin >> candName[a] >> votes[a];

        if ( ! std::cin )
            break;      // stop if they type something bad
    }
}
```

Another easy modification to make would be to store the results in a `vector` of user-defined type containing `string` and `int` , instead of having two fixed-size arrays. Then you can accept any number of inputs instead of exactly 6 .

Comment: I like that code and it makes sense to me but I don't think my instructor will like me using vectors when we have not covered them yet.

Comment: I have another active question on here and I was having to constantly alter my array sizes and I was always missing a couple so I got to putting them all as const variables so I only had to change it in one spot.

Comment: @walnut good suggestion, I have modified the code accordingly.  (although of course I'd prefer to do away with a length constant entirely)

Comment: @JeffA if you have only a single array then you would avoid problems with mismatched array lengths . The array element type can contain both the string and the int .

Answer (score -2):

This needs fixing, replace `,` with `>>` or something:

```
for (int a = 0;a < nameRow;a++)
{
    cin >> candName[a], nameCol;  // << -- here
    cin >> votes[a], voteCol;     // << -- and here
}
```

And this is a very bad style:

```
for (int c = 0; c < voteRow;c++)
    for (int d = 0; d < voteCol;d++)
        votes[c][d] = 0;
```

Please, add curly brackets like this:

```
for (int c = 0; c < voteRow;c++) {
    for (int d = 0; d < voteCol;d++) {
        votes[c][d] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Disagree with pontificating about style in an answer. Your suggested change just looks like extra screen clutter to me  .  Also the suggestion to replace `,` with `>>` will fail to compile (you cannot write to a `const` object

Comment: I don't agree about putting in unneeded braces.  What I think is: if none of the for and if statements in the nesting need braces then they don't need braces, but if even one of the for and if statements need braces then all of them need braces because otherwise you can't be sure the indenting is right.

Comment: @M.M I agree with you also.

Comment: This also doesn't solve the actual error OP is asking about, which is caused by `cin >> votes[a]` itself.